# Angular 2 ViewChild queries not run before change detector

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 2 (beta 6) component with some ViewChild queries. It uses the result of these queries in some methods that provide data to the view (e.g. measuring the size of elements). While the elements are actually constructed and added to the DOM before the methods are called, the queries aren't yet resolved.

Consider this component (http://plnkr.co/edit/4RQPagQzrZISNDLpj2Ku):

```
var Cmp = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    template: '<div class="parent" #parent>{{parentWidth()}}</div>',
    queries:{
      parent:new ng.core.ViewChild('parent')
    }
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [ng.core.ElementRef, function Cmp(el) {
      this.el = el;
    }],
    parentWidth:function() {
      if(!this.parent) {
        console.warn('Change detector run before queries instantiated');
        console.warn('But note that the element exists', this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.parent'));
        return 0;
      }
      return this.parent.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    }
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(Cmp);
});
```

The `parentWidth` method gets called before `this.parent` has been instantiated, even though the element I want to access is already in the DOM.

Is there a better way of querying elements from Javascript, or should I just go back to using `this.el.querySelector('.parent')` whenever I need something from my view?

Comment: I'm getting error in plunkr console..? did you missed something while adding plunkr to question?

Comment: No, the errors are because of the behavior I describe. Notice that in the console you get my two console warnings, followed by some Angular errors that the value of `parentWidth` has changed from 0 to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.parent... // parent is initialized 
}
```

Comment: I can't wait until after view init, because the methods are being called from the view itself.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's necessary and won't work well if you don't wait until the view is ready.

Comment: How would you recommend having an element display its own dimensions, or something calculated in a complex way from its own dimensions?

Comment: Read the dimensions in `ngAfterViewInit()` and assign it to a variable and bind the view to the variable instead of a funtion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a method expression, try this:

```
<div class="parent" #parent>{{parent?.offsetWidth}}</div>
```